# Transfer a id from one php file to another

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I'm working on a page where the User can enter an ID which then gets passed to a Controller. This Controller handles the ID and generates a uniqID. With this uniqID a new folder gets generated on the server.

[image: Process]

Now there's another PHP File which needs to access the generated Folder on the Server. To access the right folder the file needs the generated uniqID.

I tried it with Sessions. But that's a bad idea, because the user can make multiple Requests to the Controller in other Tabs and with Sessions the uniqID always gets overwritten.

How can i pass the uniqID from my Controller to the PHP File?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of approaches to do this task.

Here are few of them that I quickly came up with:

1) Store the key value mapping in database (key as the id, value as the unique number)

2) You can do that in sessions too because every id will have a unique entry, a session having an array of `KEY (id) => VALUE (unique id)` is fine too but to avoid over head and consistency, I would recommend you to save the mapping in database.

`Cons:` If there server is restarted, yon won't have any clue about the session information. It is not a good practice though.

3) You can use filing but again you need to write proper functions to retrieve and store the mappings.

Answer (score 0):

You could post the data to the file with **PHPCURL**. For example:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'yourfile.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $uniqueID['id']);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

In yourfile.php, you can fetch the data:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' AND isset($_POST['id'])){
    //execute code...
}
```

Comment: what if the user needs to access it again? after few days?

Comment: Usage of a database would definitely be easier in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the user_id and the unique_folder_id in a database table and do a lookup in the database from the php file and create the directories.

You can add a flag `done` taking 0 and 1 values to check if the folder has been created already.
Or if the amount of records permits, you could check with `file_exists` before attempting to create the directory.